# How to get the width of autogenerated wpf datagrid at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, wpfdatagrid, wpftoolkit

In my wpf application, I have an auto-generated datagrid. The number of columns shown are not fixed and may vary from 5 to 30 columns. I have to show horizontal scroll-bar on the grid if all the columns are not getting accommodated on the screen. To show the horizontal scroll bar I have to specify the width of the datagrid at run-time. So how could I get the required width of the datagrid at runtime?

Comment: Try setting the `ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property to `Auto`, or `Visible` on your `DataGrid`... they should appear automatically when needed. Actually, I think that the `DataGrid` has its own `HorizontalScrollBarVisibility` property... try setting that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Scrollviewer visibility of DataGrid and put your DataGrid inside a Grid

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.CoulmnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.CoulmnDefinitions>
   <DataGrid Grid.Column="0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <!-- Some code here -->

    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Mayur for the response. Actually I have tried this earlier and it is not showing the scrollbar. We have to set the width of the datagrid to show the horizontal scrollbar. Therefore I am looking for the solution to get/calculate the required width of the datagrid and assign it at run-time.

Comment: Assigning width at run-time is not the appropriate way to do that. Since your Data grid is re-sizing, try putting your DataGrid inside a Grid whose width is Auto. I've update my code to do that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mayur. But still horizontal scrollbar is not visible.

Comment: Checked datagrid width at runtime its showing as NaN